# using editText as a button

Tags: android

I made an EditTest `focusable="false"`.

How do I move to next   XML form using EditText?

Is it possible?

how to use the onclicklistner for edittext?

```
android:id="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Agenda Template"
android:ems="10"

android:focusable="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your edittext `android:clickable="true"` and add the click listener as below:

> ```
>  <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/refresh"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:ems="10" 
>     android:clickable="true"
>     android:focusable="false">
>
>    EditText m_et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);            
>         m_et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View p_v) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         System.out.println("EditeText Cliecket ===============");
>             }
>         });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText ev;
Button b;
TextView tv;
static String str;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ev=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("edittext button");

        }
    });
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            str=ev.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(str);
            //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ev.getWindowToken(), 0);


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    }

  }
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

use OnTouchListener on editText instead on onClickListene.
This may work.